# Ad-Hoc Wireless Network Connectivity

Tags: wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network

Is it necessary for all the participating nodes in a wireless ad-hoc network to be in the vicinity of each other?

Suppose there are three nodes, all connected to the same ad-hoc network (configured explicitly): A, B, C. If A is too far from C to be within wireless range, but is close to B, can it communicate to C via B?

Will every node broadcast frames that it can see but are not addressed to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBSS networks (which is what people usually mean by ad-hoc networks) do not do forwarding.

For that, you need a mesh network (like 802.11s, which is still a draft standard).

Comment: might wanna do your homework first: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_ad_hoc_network

Comment: I did do my homework. I only forgot to explicitly mention that by "ad-hoc" most people mean an IBSS (since "ad-hoc" is what the user interface says in these cases), which indeed does no forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where node A is, it will pick a node to act as it's access point (like a router in a regular wireless setup).This access point will forward data for node A if A cannot access it locally.